# Trouble iterating through GeoJSON files

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

I have a number of GeoJSON files that I am trying to combine into one DataFrame.  When I open them individually with GeoPandas.read_file, there are no issues.  However, when I attempt to iterate through the files, I get the following error:

```
CPLE_OpenFailedError: b'Failed to read GeoJSON data'
```

Here is my code:

```
directory = 'C:\\Users\\Data\\output'
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    df2 = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(directory,filename))
    df = df.append(df2)
```

Printing os.path.join(directory, filename) yields the correct string, so I don't understand why this is not working as I understand it should.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.  Some of the files were empty, creating the error.  The below code works.

```
directory = 'C:\\Users\\Data\\output'
df = pd.DataFrame()
errors = []
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    try:
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        df2 = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(directory,filename))
        df = df.append(df2)
    except:
        errors.append(filename)
```